# ¿Como obtener resultados enteros en las variables con la clase SimplexSolver de la librería de Apache Commons Math?

Tags: java, apache

estoy realizando una aplicación que usa el método Simplex para obtener la mayor utilidad en una función, para usar este método hago uso de la clase [SimplexSolver](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/linear/SimplexSolver.html) presente en la librería de Apache Commons Math 3.6, el problema es que hasta ahora no he podido encontrar una función o una forma en la que los resultados de las variables de la función sean estrictamente enteros, ya que en el programa me arroja resultados con números decimales que afectan la solución real del problema.

Comment: no se puede ocupar parseInt sobre la variable?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, el problema no es de convertir los resultados a enteros, eso se puede hacer facilmente con parseInt como tú dices, lo que quiero es agregar la restricción de que los resultados sean enteros, ya que sin esa restricción el programa no me entrega los resultados deseados, por ejemplo en un caso donde quiera que una variable tenga valor uno y otra valor cero, este me puede generar un valor en 0.5 en ambas variables, espero haber sido claro.